# yii2 ActiveRecord Find OrderBy with calculation

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii2

Trying to fetch a description from my database.
The query returns the result but I would like to order the result to only show the one with the highest vote.

The vote should be calculated by the `upvoted` column subtracted by the `downvoted` column

```
$description = UnitDescription::find()
   ->where(['id_unit' => $model->id])
   ->orderBy([
      'upvoted - downvoted' => SORT_DESC //Need this line to be fixed
   ])
   ->one();
```

I was hoping someone might have a way to write this part of the query - Thanks

Comment: show table structure.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should simply try :

```
$description = UnitDescription::find()
    ->where(['id_unit' => $model->id])
    ->orderBy(['(upvoted - downvoted)' => SORT_DESC])
    ->one();
```

Comment: Wow, already upvoted this. So thanks twice for this answer, it's helped me more than once :)