# yii2 joinWith sort not work when i have two block order by

Tags: mysql, activerecord, group-by, yii2, sql-order-by

hello every one i have a problem, with mysql order by, here is my yii2 query, but
i have two order by block, first block inside inline function work correctly. but 
second order by block not work. I find out i can not use two block order by but what is the solution in have some product and product details each product have some product details price column is inside product_details i want select expensive product with cheep product_details here is my code not work because i have two block order by :

```
  $query = Product::find()
            ->joinWith('category')
            ->joinWith([
                'productGurantyColorPrices' => function (ActiveQuery $q) use ($st) {
                    $q->andFilterWhere([
                        '{{%product_guranty_color_price}}.color_id' => $this->color_id
                    ])
                        ->andFilterWhere([
                            '{{%product_guranty_color_price}}.guranty_id' 
                            =>$this->guranty_id
                        ])
                        ->andFilterWhere([
                            'between', '{{%product_guranty_color_price}}.price_off', $this->min_price, $this->max_price
                        ]);
                    $q->andWhere(['visible' => 1]);
                    $q->andFilterWhere(['status_available' => $this->status_available]);
                    $q->orderBy("status_available,`status_available`=$st,- `price_off` DESC");
                }
            ])
            ->groupBy("{{%product}}.id")
            ->where([
                '{{%product}}.status' => Product::STATUS_ACTIVE,
                '{{%product_guranty_color_price}}.status' => ProductGurantyColorPrice::STATUS_ACTIVE,
                'site_visiable' => 1,//مال محصول
                'visible' => 1,//مال گارانتی
            ]);
        $query->orderBy("status_available ASC,- `price_off` DESC,{{%product}}.changed DESC");
```

here is converted query in mysql:

```
  SELECT `ec_product`.* 
FROM `ec_product` LEFT JOIN `ec_category` ON 
`ec_product`.`category_id` = `ec_category`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `ec_product_guranty_color_price` ON `ec_product`.`id` = `ec_product_guranty_color_price`.`product_id` 
WHERE ((`ec_product`.`status`=1) AND (`ec_product_guranty_color_price`.`status`=1) AND
 (`site_visiable`=1) AND 
(`visible`=1)) AND 
(`visible`=1) GROUP BY
 `ec_product`.`id` ORDER BY
 `status_available`, - `price_off` DESC, `ec_product`.`changed` DESC, `status_available`=1
```

Comment: orderBy must be an array. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588843/yii2-activerecord-find-orderby-with-calculation#34589376

Comment: there is no difference between array and text yii2 work with they both

Comment: Have you tried checking the resulting mysql command?

Comment: use `echo $query->createCommand()->rawSql` to print the query and add it inside your Question by editing

Comment: SELECT `ec_product`.* FROM `ec_product` LEFT JOIN `ec_category` ON `ec_product`.`category_id` = `ec_category`.`id` LEFT JOIN `ec_product_guranty_color_price` ON `ec_product`.`id` = `ec_product_guranty_color_price`.`product_id` WHERE ((`ec_product`.`status`=1) AND (`ec_product_guranty_color_price`.`status`=1) AND (`site_visiable`=1) AND (`visible`=1)) AND (`visible`=1) GROUP BY `ec_product`.`id` ORDER BY `status_available`, - `price_off` DESC, `ec_product`.`changed` DESC, `status_available`=1